# style all the child element without classes?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple nav ul li a that i need to style different and I have no good way of doing this. I've looked around the net for quite a bit but i do not understand how to do this without using class="" in every element. My code is below. There must be a better way of doing this? Like all children that has class="loginmenu" should be like x and all children of class="dropdownmenu" should be like y. Even if they are the same element.

```
 <nav class="loginmenu">
    <ul class="loginmenu">
        <li class="loginmenu">
           <p><a href="main_login.php">Login</a></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<nav class="dropdownmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="gigs">
            <p><a href="gigs.php">Gigs</a></p>
            <p class="subtext">Shows & Gigs</p>
        </li>

        <li class="music">
            <p><a href="music.php">Music</a></p>
            <p class="subtext">Tracks & Sets</p>
        </li>

        <li class="booking">
            <p><a href="booking.php">Booking</a></p>
            <p class="subtext">Booking & Contact</p>
        </li>
```

CSS:

```
nav.loginmenu {
    position: absolute;
}
li.loginmenu{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 1200px;

} and so on...
```

Comment: This is the only line in your question that even attempts to explain what you're trying to do: "I have multiple nav ul li a that i need to style different."... Why don;t you try explaining yourself a little better.

Comment: You're probably looking for the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#Selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nav.loginmenu <element>`.

```
nav.loginmenu li {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 1200px;
}
```

For more information see [the documentation of CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) or try [CSS Selector tester](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp).

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules can represent a hierarchy. For instance, the following means: "*Apply this rule to all li elements that are inside a nav element with class loginmenu*")

```
nav.loginmenu li {
  ..
}
```

It's commonplace for me to add classes to one root element that has no rules of its own, but for which having that class affects behavior of its children.

When sharing functionality, it is also common to add one class to multiple elements, or multiple classes to one element (separated by spaces) if it simply represents certain behavior (eg, applying a margin to all list elements to give them a "tabbing" look)

Additionally, many properties (most of the font-... properties for instance) are inherited from parent to child unless they're overridden at a lower level, so there's no need to repeat those for further descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. But if I'm interpreting correctly, you want to target different elements within each `<nav>` element? If so you can add an **id** which should be unique (not repeated) to your `<nav>` element then target the element like so:

html:

```
<nav id="loginMenu">
    ...
</nav>
```

css:

```
#loginMenu li {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 1200px;
}
```

Or you can use Genhis answer.

Comment: Tried both answers and it seems so far to be the same in my case as long as i dont use the ID more than one. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: Also, IDs are not meant to be used more than once. That's what classes are for